# Where does the energy of the decaying CMB go?

Tags: cosmology, light, cosmic-microwave-background

I would expect that energy of photons in the [Cosmic ray Microwave Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) gets less and less because their wavelengths are stretched due to the expansion of space.

How can this be possible? Does it only look like their wavelength is increasing because we, as observers are not "expanding along"?

Where does the energy of the decaying CMB go?

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/259759/123208 & links therein.

Comment: [It doesn't go anywhere](https://kaiserscience.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/is-the-universe-leaking-energy-law-conservation.pdf).

Comment: @planetmaker But the wavelength of each photon decreases. This means (the number of photons stays the same) that the total energy goes down. (as seen from our perspective).

Comment: @pela That's a very nice article!

Comment: @planetmaker In the article linked by Pela, Tamara Davis mentions that the apparent energy lost via redshift is *not* balanced by the creation of dark energy.

Comment: @PM2Ring Is it just an apparent loss? Because *we* are not expanding, so to speak? So *it looks* as if the wavelength of the photons is growing? So seen from us dark energy *has* to be there to compensate?

Comment: @PM2Ring interesting... thanks!

Comment: Barbierium, you should check out Prof Davis's [homepage](https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/). There's lots of great stuff in the Research section and videos in the Talks and Outreach section. FWIW, her PhD topic was on the expansion of space, and her papers and popular articles "Clarifying common misconceptions about the expansion of the universe and cosmic horizons" are *very* highly regarded.

Comment: Wavelength of incoming photon is defined by the frequency of said photon. And frequency is defined relative to time. As space expands fast enough the time dilation explained by GR makes it appear that the photons are losing energy when we measure the frequency *relative to our local time*.